# The difference between retain count and reference count in swift

Tags: swift, memory-management

What is difference between retain   count  and reference count in swift ?   Or they both are same ?  Can any body explain it to me ?

Comment: Neither matters. Swift uses automatic reference counting.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between them in manual reference count

Comment: There is no manual reference count in Swift.

Comment: Only thing you need to worry about is retain cycles, which I explain here http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_memory_management

Comment: Ok.in objective c , what is the difference between them ?

Comment: I explain here http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The retain count is an internal count maintained by an object: how many times an unbalanced `retain` has been sent to that object.

The reference count is an external fact: how many objects have a reference to this object.

The goal of memory management, at heart, is to keep those two numbers the same at all times.