# In Swift, what is the accurate way to check the reference count of an class object in memory?

Tags: swift, memory-management, reference-counting

English is not my native language, so please excuse any typing errors. I am using a translator for my question.

I learned from watching "[WWDC16 - Understanding Swift Performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/?time=1327)" that when allocating memory for a class on the heap, it allocates 2 words more than on the stack.

**The first word of the 2 words is a pointer to the type information of that class, and the second word is the reference count.**

To verify this, I wrote the following code:

```swift
class RefType {
    var num1: Int
    var num2: Int

    init(num1: Int, num2: Int) {
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
    }
}

func test() {
    var ref1 = RefType(num1: 5, num2: 9) // 03 00
    var ref2 = ref1 // 03 02

    print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(ref1).toOpaque()) // 0x0000600000206a00
    print("job done") // <- breakpoint
}

test()
```

**By inspecting the memory through the address of `ref1`, I got the following results:**

[result1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIJZE.jpg)

I thought that the value `05` and `09` that were passed in while creating the class are assigned, and the word preceding `05` represents the reference count *(second block highlighted in blue)*

To make sure, I added another variable that references `ref1` and wrote the provided code.

```swift
var ref1 = RefType(num1: 5, num2: 9) // 03 00
var ref2 = ref1 // 03 02
var ref3 = ref1 // added
```

While expecting the reference count to increase by 1 and become `03`, it was `04` instead.

[result2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEkTq.jpg)

I dont understand why it increases by 2 each time a new reference is added and also what does the `03 00 00 00` at the first 4bytes means??

## Summary

1. Although I understand that the blue-highlighted part represents the reference count of the class, I don't know the meaning of the value(`03`) pointed by the first 4 bytes.
2. I'm curious about why the reference count increases by 2 as the number of references increases.

I'm new here and my reputation is not enough, so I had to replace the pictures with links. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing the reference count and the retain count?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Isn't the thing being added within a class a reference count? In WWDC16's "Understanding Swift Performance" session at 12:51, they mention that class initialized with a reference count of one. (also in presentation slide)

Comment: I also read this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890203/the-difference-between-retain-count-and-reference-count-in-swift
 but now I'm a little confused about whether the thing being added within a class is a retain count or a reference count.